# What is wrong in my code? The program just terminates without error statement

Tags: c, pointers, structure

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct stucture
{
    int info;
};
typedef struct stucture * ts;

int main()
{
   ts exp;
   exp->info=10;
   printf("working");
}
```

I don't know what is wrong with this piece of code. No error statement is printed so as to look for a solution. The program just terminates.

Comment: Don't hide pointer semantics behind a typedef... If you hadn't, `exp->info` would probably look way more suspicious to you.

Comment: You have not allocate memory to the pointer `exp`. You can not store until you allocate. allocate first using `malloc` and then initialize variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That pointer points to nothing valid. You can do this to get a valid result.

```
struct structure ab;
ts exp = &ab;
```

Now earlier on your program you accessed some indeterminate memory location and the program crashes (undefined behavior).

Or you can dynamically allocate memory to get a valid result

```
ts exp = malloc(sizeof *exp);
if ( exp == NULL ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in allocation");
    exit(1);
}
...
//do cool stuff with exp
...
free(exp);
```

Freeing the memory is a must when you dynamically allocate memory using `malloc`.

#### So what went wrong?...

A pointer variable is supposed to store address. Now the `ts` is actually denoting a `struct structure*`.

Whose address will it contain then? `struct structure`'s address.

Initially `exp` contains some indeterminate values. You don't even know if it's a valid address or if it is permitted to access it. You try to access it - and it's undefined behavior.

Here when you do

```
struct structure ab;
ts exp = &ab;
```

You are basically making `exp` point to `ab`'s address. Now when you dereference it you access a valid memory location and make changes to it.

---

Also here you have misinterpreted that you have hidden a pointer under that typedef.

If you did this

```
typedef struct structure ts;
```

And then if you do something like this

```
  ts exp
  exp.info = 10;
```

That would be valid.

---

The key takeaways would be:-

- Don't hide pointers inside `typedef` , it's make it more difficult to manage your program.
- Use better naming `struct structure` is not a good name.
- What the heck is [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)??
- How to use `malloc`?

Comment: I'd prefer to wrap up whatever after `sizeof` in parentheses.

Comment: @iBug.: Not necessary. This also works. But yes you can do that.

Answer (score 6):

Hiding pointers behind a `typedef` and still using them as pointers is a dumb idea.

There's no error message because your program is semantically correct, without any compile-time error. That does not, however, mean there's no [runtime error](https://techterms.com/definition/runtime_error) as well.

`typedef` only create aliases for existing types, therefore

```
ts exp;
```

makes absolutely no difference from

```
struct structure *exp;
```

which looks clearer now. With that statement, where'd you expect `exp` to be pointing to?

Being unitialized, it can actually point to **anywhere** in the memory, so accessing it is definitely an [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You must at least give it a valid address to point to before trying to access:

```
struct structure x;
exp = &x;
```

or with dynamic allocation:

```
exp = malloc(sizeof(*exp));
if (exp == NULL) {
    fputs("Failed to allocate memory", stderr);
    exit(1);
}
// Do stuff
free(exp);
```

Don't forget the last `free()` statement or you'll run into another problem: memory leak.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Sorry but I don't quite understand "tonight". I'm in China and it's 15:35 here (GMT+8)

Comment: Correction -- today (same postscript).